# Add a log analytics workspace to Azure VM without replacing existing workspaces

Tags: azure, powershell

I have the following Powershell command

```
Set-AzVMExtension -ExtensionName "MicrosoftMonitoringAgent" `
                -ResourceGroupName "rg-xxxx" `
                -VMName "vm-xxxx" `
                -Publisher "Microsoft.EnterpriseCloud.Monitoring" `
                -ExtensionType "MicrosoftMonitoringAgent" `
                -TypeHandlerVersion "1.0" `
                -Settings @{"workspaceId" = "xxxx" } `
                -ProtectedSettings @{"workspaceKey" = "xxxx"} `
                -Location "uksouth"
```

which successfully replaces all Log Analytic Workspaces on the VM with the one I have configured in the command.
What I want to do is only add the workspace without replacing the ones already configured.

ARM has the same behaviour. It looks like if there is one workspace already then this gets overwritten, if there are two workspaces there, one of them gets overwritten.

Does anyone know any method within Powershell to only add a workspace and not overwrite?
Thanks,
Neil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we use the Log Analytics agent virtual machine extension to install Log Analytics agent on Azure VM, we just can enrolls virtual machines into one existing Log Analytics workspace. Every time we install the extension, Microsoft will replace the old configuration file. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/oms-windows).

If you want to add a workspace, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/agent-manage#adding-or-removing-a-workspace)

Comment: Yeah that's pretty much how I did it. Thanks for the response.